# How do I unwrap an FSharpOption of unknown depth?

Tags: .net, f#

I have an object of type FSharpOption, but I don't know it's depth. It could be any of...

```
FSharpOption<Int32>
FSharpOption<FSharpOption<Int32>>
FSharpOption<FSharpOption<FSharpOption<Int32>>>
FSharpOption<FSharpOption<FSharpOption<FSharpOption<Int32>>>>
etc.
```

Edit: Also note that it isn't necessarily an Int32. It could be any underlying type.

How do I get at the underling value using VB or C#?

Comment: How did you manage to create such an object? Can you show the producing F# code?

Comment: @Johan, this is a generic interop library. It doesn't represent a concert issue but rather a more general "what if" kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may not be version independent... how about this minor variation with no dependency on FSharp.Core?

```
static object OptionGetUnderlyingValue(object obj)
{
    while (obj != null && obj.GetType().Name == "FSharpOption`1")
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
        Contract.Assert(pi != null);
        obj = pi.GetValue(obj, null);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Nice touch. It might be a little slower, but then again it might not be.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help but wonder how you got into this state in the first place.

That said, assuming the static type is 'object', then I guess you'll have to see if its .GetType() is the generic type definition of FSharpOption`1, and use reflection (or 'dynamic') to unwrap one level and try again...

I am unclear how this is an F# question, since you want the answer in C# or VB, and the same question could be asked of any Foo<T> type.

That all said, here's some C# 4.0 code:

```
    object o = FS.Foo.F(3);
    while (o.GetType().IsGenericType && 
           o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
              typeof(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption<>))
    {
        dynamic d = o;
        o = d.Value;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(o);
```

and some F# code:

```
namespace FS

type Foo() = 
    static member F x =
        match x with
        | 1 -> Some 42 |> box
        | 2 -> Some(Some "forty-two") |> box
        | 3 -> Some(Some(Some 42)) |> box
        | _ -> failwith "no"
```

EDIT note that I changed it to show the strategy works even if it contains things other than just ints.

Comment: (realization) Hey wow, I used 'dynamic' without even really thinking about it!

Comment: I am working on a generic interop library for C#/VB applciations that need to deal with F# types. This is a bit of an edge case, but so long as F# supports unlimited nesting I need to account for it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean my "F# supports unlimited nesting".  You could "have the same problem" with System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.  "I have an object that's int, or List<int>, or List<List<int>>, or ..."  Nothing F# here.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean by unlimited nesting. As a contrast, Nullable<T> cannot be nested.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is what I have so far. Any suggestions on improving it?

```
Option Strict Off
Imports Microsoft.FSharp.Core

Public Module FSharpInterop
    Public Function OptionGetUnderlyingValue(ByVal value As Object) As Object
        If value Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Dim temp = value
        Do While temp.GetType.Name = "FSharpOption`1"
            temp = OptionModule.GetValue(temp)
            If temp Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Loop
        Return temp
    End Function
End Module
```